# Using Selenium, best way to verify something is not on the page after a max time?

Tags: selenium

Using Selenium, what would be the best way (or design pattern) to verify something is not on the page after a max time?

I know we could wait for a element to appear with a string on it, like so:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });
```

BUT, what if I wanted to make sure that for 10 seconds, **the OPPOSITE** was true, and no element had appeared on the page with a certain text in it?   Basically, a condition that is expected to usually, but not always, reach the max timeout.

In my use case, its important that the call to the method not throw any exceptions that will exit the JUnit/TestNG test case and instead always allow successive test steps to continue and the final softAsserts to occur.

The method should have a signature like this:

```
Boolean verifyElementWithTextDoesNotAppear( By locator, String, text, long timeout )
```

Is there a good design pattern that any of you use that could do this most efficiently?  The method must not throw a **TimeoutException** nor throw any particular type of **WebDriverException** before or after the timeout is reached and must likely instead  return a reliable boolean result.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess so far, if you expect a FALSE, calling this method would be safe, I think:

```
public Boolean elementExistsWithinSeconds(By locator, int seconds)
{
    ExpectedCondition<List<WebElement>> elementListCondition = 
           ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator);
    WebDriverWait wait = webDriverManager.getCachedWebDriverWait(seconds);
    try {
        List<WebElement> elementList = wait.until(elementListCondition);
        if ( elementList.size() > 0 ) return Boolean.TRUE;
    } catch ( TimeoutException te ) {
        LOG.debug( "Element '" + locator.toString() + "' with text '" + text +
             "' was not found within timeout.", te);            
    }
    return Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In testng, we have a feature which doesnt throw the exception. expectedExceptions = NoSuchElementException.class put in the @Test method.

Comment: Also, using a FluentWait from Selenium, you can do a .ignoring fluent command that ignores exceptions also but this is not what my question is about.  I could not find a single example on the net similar to what I am trying to do, which is why I am asking it.